# ¿Se puede modificar el orden de las columnas en una entidad en base de datos H2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@Entity
@Table(name = "PRICES")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class Price {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @Column(name = "PRICE_LIST")
    private Long priceList;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
    private Long priority;

    @Column(name = "PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "CURR")
    private String curr;

    @Column(name = "BRAND_ID")
    private Long brandId;
}
```

A la hora de la creación obtengo esta tabla así formada:
ID  BRAND_ID    CURR    END_DATE    PRICE   PRICE_LIST      PRIORITY    PRODUCT_ID      START_DATE

Me gustaría que el orden de creación u ordenación fuese el siguiente: ID     START_DATE    END_DATE      PRICE_LIST     PRODUCT_ID    PRIORITY    PRICE     CURR

Para que tenga mejor aspecto visual, esto debe hacerlo Hibernate y el gestor de BDDD H2 en este caso esta en memoria.

¿Se podría hacer de alguna manera? que sea creando la entidad no haciendo una query.

Gracias

Comment: Considera implementar [*ColumnOrderingStrategy*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/ColumnOrderingStrategy.html).